# Static route gives "Destination host unreachable" error

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, route

I have a server (Windows Server 2012) with 2 network interfaces.
One with a 172.0.0.0 network, which has the default gateway (172.16.8.254)
And one with a 10.0.0.0 network, no gateway set.

[image: Network config]

Since by default, all communcation wil go through the default gateway. I use persistent static routes to force 10.0.0.0 traffic through the second network interface. But there are some exceptions which should go through the default gateway anyway. I fix this with masking and metrics.

[image: Routing table]

This usually works fine. But for some reason, my latest addition. The 10.116.0.0 subnet, doesn't work.
When I try to ping it, the correct gateway shows up, but it appears as an unreachable host, whilst other subnets with a similar setup, work fine through that same gateway.

[image: Pinging test]

What could be the reason that the gateway fails for this particular subnet? It works fine for all the other persistent routes.

Comment: What is answering when you ping a network?

Comment: As you can see in the ping of the other subnets, the default gateway through which the subnet gets routed. Anyway I can't reach any host on the 10.116 subnet.

Comment: That's what I was wondering, if there was already at least one system in that subnet.  Now you should check your router's config, the 172.168.8.254, why it can't reach the 10.116.0.0 subnet.

Comment: Run `tracert` instead.